# Requesting OAuth Token from Zoom API

Tags: oauth, zoom-sdk

i have this api in .net core :
[HttpGet("authorize")]

```
    public IActionResult Authorize()
    {
        var clientId = _configuration["ZoomAppSettings:ClientId"];
        var redirectUri = _configuration["ZoomAppSettings:RedirectUri"];

        var authorizeUrl = $"https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={redirectUri}";

        return Redirect(authorizeUrl);


    }
```

and i also configer Client ID and Client Secret in appsetting.json file but when i hit the api from swager it will return zoom signin page html code in response body, but i want to go to that page and click on authorize page so can i get code in callback

i tried all things and all flow according to oAuth 2.0 zoom api integration documentation